# For all integers $m$ and $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove:
For all integers $m$ and $n$, if $m+n$ is even then so is $m-n$. 
Would you just set them even to each other because you are given $m+n$ is even?

Comment: What do you mean by “even to each other”?

Answer (score 4):

You know that $m+n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Note that $m-n=m+n-2n$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I am thinking:

You have $m + n = 2k$ for some integer $k$ since $m + n$ is even

Let $m = 2k - n$

Now $m - n = 2k - n - n = 2k - 2n = 2(k - n)$

Therefore $2(k-n)$ must be even since any integer multiplied by $2$ is even.

Comment: This is perfectly fine (+1), but the “Let m=2k-n” does not fit there. You already have chosen $m$, $n$, $k$ with $m+n=2k$, so $m=2k-n$ is not an additional assumption but a consequence.